# How to correctly cache query results when using EF Core with a lot of Include()?

Tags: c#, caching, entity-framework-core

I am using https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor package to cache EF Core query results in my ASP.NET Core app. According to creator, it works like that:

> The results of EF commands will be stored in the cache, so that the
> same EF commands will retrieve their data from the cache rather than
> executing them against the database again.

So this library returns cached results if the generated SQL is the same.

The problem is that I am using a lot of Include() methods while querying database. This is needed due to some pages showing a lot of information that is stored in different related database tables.
Also, the query contains current-user-specific info, e.g. if the current user liked the **Post** or not. Caching user-specific info is not right as I heard and results in redundant cache entries since the only data that is changing is the current user ID.

Example of a query:

```
var post = dbContext.Posts
   .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
   .Include(p => p.Comments)
   .Include(p => p.VoteTracker
               .Where(t => t.UserId == "{current user ID}"))
   // ... other Include(...) calls
   .ToList();
```

The SQL generated can be quite huge with a lot of JOINs. So the problem with caching here are:

1. if **Comments** get changed, then the whole query above will be invalidated aswell since this library

> watches for all of the CRUD operations using its interceptor and
> then invalidates the related cache entries automatically

2. Having current-user-specific info in the query creates a lot of identical cache entries, which are only varying by that current-user-specific info

What is the better approach for caching here?

The first thing that comes to mind is to have separate queries that can be cached. For example:

```
// Post and Comments query will be cached
var post = dbContext.Posts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);

var comments = dbContext.Comments
    .Where(c => c.PostId == 1)
    .ToList();

// This one will be excluded from caching (because of user-specific info)
var voteTracker = dbContext.VoteTrackers
    .SingleOrDefault(t => t.PostId == 1 && t.UserId == "{current user ID}");
```

Is it a good approach? And if it's not which one is better?

I am struggling with this a lot, but having a hard time finding the right solution. Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, can u plz share yr workaround